# Get Same response in node as coming from angular

Tags: angularjs, node.js

I am developin app in angularjs and nodejs. I want to upload the image using angular and node. Image is sern dusing multipart/form-data. when i send data post request looks like:

```
{name="customer.pen.13",  email="temp@temp.com",  website="http://www.tels-tra.com,image:FileList { 0=File,  length=1,  item=item()}}
```

I want to get same format in nodejs.But in my node js I got:

```
{name="customer.pen.13",  email="temp@temp.com",  website="http://www.tels-tra.com}
```

Image is missing in request.

Here is my code:

```
exports.updateExchangeSetup = function(req, res, next) {
    var request = require('request');
    console.log(req);
      console.log(req.body);
}
var headers = {
    'headers': {
        'User-Agent': 'Super Agent/0.0.1',
        'Authorization': 'test',
        'Access-Control-Allow-Methods': 'POST, GET, PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS',
        "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
        "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept,Authorization",
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As per very short description from you code snippets, I am assuming you are using **expressJS** on the server side, could you please check the content-type you are handling on express side. I think its application/JSON, and it makes your app disable to understand multipart form data. However I need more details on nodeJs side to answer better.

Answer (score 0):

Everything looks okay as per your snippets. Are you putting your image data on URL?

```
"http://www.tels-tra.com,image:FileList { 0=File,  length=1,  item=item()}}"
```

if this is a string, then it should not get tempered.

Instead of your snippet you could try the following example to upload image and sending other parameters. Maybe this is not the exact solution you are looking for, but it may give you an idea if you are dealing with file upload with extra parameters.

Use `ngFileUpload`at angular to upload file

```
Upload.upload({
    url: "/api/enpoint/resources",
    data: {file: filePath, 'name': "customer.pen.13", 'email'="temp@temp.com"},
    headers: {/* your header object here */}
}).then(function (res) {
  // do something
  });
```

#### Node/ExpressJS router

use `connect-multiparty` middleware to intercept file

```
var multipartyMiddleware = require('connect-multiparty')();
router.post('/api/enpoint/resources',multipartyMiddleware, ctrl.updateExchangeSetup);
```

#### Node/ExpressJS Controller

```
exports.updateExchangeSetup = function(req, res, next) {
    // files will be at: req.files
    var imageFile = req.files.file;
    var email = req.body.email
}
```